# Separate into new rows within cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to modify/format text which is in the cell like:
[image: this is formatted text that I don't want]

If the text contains ";" or bullets, to make a new row.

Briefly, I copy that cell into noteped (.txt), and it copies multiple bullets in one row, or with ";". I want to make a new row. For now, I modify it manually.

Thanks!

Edit:

```
Sub foo1()

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim FullName As Variant
Dim oldText As String
txt = Cells(2, 5)
FullName = Split(txt, ";")

For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
   oldText = Cells(2, 1).Value
   Cells(2, 1).Value = oldText & vbCrLf & "•" & FullName(i)

Next
End Sub
```

I've succeed. Only two questions: 1. How to put two delimiters? 2. Why when I copy cell value into notepad it wraps it with ""?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You should use the `Split` function to split the output and forward it into an array. After that you can use the `Transpose` function to turn the array so that it becomes a list.

Comment: @Calum please view my edit.  I've managed for the first break, but I dont know how, to insert a whole array into one cell.

Comment: Yeah you could use a `Split` function like so to add to next line down when it finds ";" `Dim Cnumbers() As String
  Cnumbers = Split(Selection.Value, ";")
  Selection(1).Resize(UBound(Cnumbers) + 1) = Application.Transpose(Cnumbers)`

Comment: @Calum please view my latest edit. I want two delimiters and to avoid quotes when I copy to notepad. Seems it is unavoidable. Can I put some code, to open that notepad and though vba delete first and last char ("")? Thanks

Comment: Could you use something like `=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"●",CHAR(10)),";",CHAR(10)))` instead of VBA?

Comment: So to clarify, looking at your code it only copys the first value before the ";" into the row, you want it to copy every single one as a seperate bullet point?

Comment: @Calum exactly. Besides ";" I want to use multi-delimiter with ";" "." "bullet". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want it in multiple cells:

```
Sub fool()

  Dim txt as String, txt2 as variant

  txt = Replace(Cells(2, 5), ".", ";")
  txt2 = Split(txt, ";")

  Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Ubound(txt2) + 2, 1) = _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(txt2)

End Sub
```

If u want all in one cell:

```
Sub fool()

  Dim txt as String

  txt = Replace(Cells(2, 5), ".", vbCrLf)
  txt = Replace(txt, ";", vbCrLf)

  Cells(2, 1) = txt

End Sub
```

hmm... if u want to keep the old text in cell(2, 1) then change last line to:

```
        Cells(2, 1) = Cells(2, 1) & vbCrLf & txt
```

edit: or a clean way:

```
Sub fool()

  Dim txt As String, i As Byte

  txt = Cells(2, 1) & vbCrLf & Cells(2, 5)

  'change all delimeters
  For i = 0 To 2
    txt = Replace(txt, Array(".", ";", "•")(i), vbCrLf)
  Next

  'eliminate doubles
  Do While InStr(txt, vbCrLf) > 0
    txt = Replace(txt, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
  Loop

  Cells(2, 1) = txt

End Sub
```

Comment: After "Replace" each different delimeter to one (like "." to ";" and "bullet" to ";")  you can freely use "Split" with just one delimeter

Comment: That's it! I incorporated your code in mine. Great! :) Thanks!